# Run mousedown event every 0.2s, until mouse up

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, settimeout

I am trying to consecutively add +1 to the value of a text input field when the user clicks a button.

Simplified, my JQuery code is something like this:

```
$('#button').on({
 mousedown : function () {
 var value = $(this).val();
 $(this).val(value + 1);
 },
 mouseup : function () {
 //Some other stuff here
 }
});
```

This works every time the user clicks the button. 
What I want is if the user keeps the button pressed, the mousedown event to fire every 0.2s until he stops pressing (and than the mouseup event fires).

I figure this should somehow be done with setTimeout() but I would be glad if someone showed me how. Thanks.

Comment: every 0.2ms, now that's fast!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`:

```
var interval;
$('#button').on({
  mousedown : function () {
    var el = $(this);
    el.val(parseInt(el.val(), 10) + 1);
    interval = window.setInterval(function(){
      el.val(parseInt(el.val(), 10) + 1);
    }, 200);
  },
  mouseup : function () {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
});
```

However, it's not possible to run as often as every 0.2 ms, I suppose that you mean every 0.2 seconds...

Comment: In fact, your solution is quite better than mine... ;-P

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to repeat the event after the mousedown code

```
var int = null;
$("#button").mousedown(function() {
  // Start the timer on mousedown
  int = setInterval(function() {
    $("#button").val($("#button").val() + 1);
  }, 2);
}).mouseup(function() {
  // Stop the timer after mouse up
  clearInterval(int);
  int = null;
  // Other code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this like that:

```
$('#button').on({
    mousedown: function () {
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
        var self = this;
        var process = function() {
            if ($(self).data('clicked')) {
                console.log("process...");
                setTimeout(process, 200);
            }
        };
        process();
    },
    mouseup: function () {
        $(this).data('clicked', false);
    }
});
```